# Confused in using java generics proper way

Tags: java

I have struck at one point where i am not sure how to move ahead.I have a class with following code

```
public class MyClass{

  private Class<? extends ValidationProvider> providerClass;
  //getter ans setter

}
```

Provider class is being passed at run time and there can be different implementation for that, all it needs to follow the above contract `? extends ValidationProvider`.

In my implementation i have provided a property where user can pass the provider name class and based on that i need to move ahead.In order to move ahead i need to get an Instance of provider class using the build in dependency injection mechanism like

```
 public class MyClass{

      private Class<? extends ValidationProvider> providerClass;
      //getter ans setter

      public void setProvider(){
         providerClass=container.getInstance("type","name");
      }
    }
```

Signature of `container.getInstance("type","name");` is

```
 <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type, String name);
```

i am not sure how to pass type to the container and to get instance of the provider class(since provider class has a signature `<? extends ValidationProvider>` ).

for simple use case i can do like

```
container.getInstance(String.class,"my constant");
```

but not sure how to do it for my use-case
Any help in this regard will really be appreciated.

Comment: The signature of `container.getInstance("type","name")` is obviously not `Class<T>, String`. If you are really passing in Strings, then there's no way for type safety to be maintained, therefore the whole Generics shebang falls apart.

Comment: Am I getting this right? You want to look up the class object by *its* class object? So you want to pass something like `container.getInstance(ValidatationProvider<String>.class.getClass(), name)`;

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back... Your requirement is that `MyClass` should be configurable with different implementations of `ValidationProvider`, which I am assuming from your syntax is a superclass. I don't think your need generics in `MyClass` to achieve this:

```
public class MyClass{

    private ValidationProvider provider;

    public void setProvider(ValidationProvider _provider){
        this.provider = _provider;
    }
}
```

Then if (for example) the configuration is achieved by having the fully-qualified name of the exact provider implementation in a config file, you can set your instance of `MyClass` as follows:

```
...
String validatorClassName;
...
// Assign validatorClassName a value from a config file
...
ValidationProvider v = container.getInstance(Class.forName(validatorClassName), "blah");
myClass.setProvider(v);
```

Comment: OP wants to have statically ensured that proper class is passed to the object. This would be possible only if class literals are used and impossible if using strings. If strings are used, then your advice is sound: OP should relinquish all hope of static type safety.